# How to pass an unsigned argument to a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have two files - One from which I am passing an unsigned argument to the template, another which contains the template declaration and definition.

```
/*File1.cc */
#include "File2.h"
int main()
{
    unsigned n = 10;
    ThreadPool<n> pool;  //Error
.....
}




/* File_2.h */
....
namespace nbsdx {
namespace concurrent {

template <unsigned ThreadCount>
class ThreadPool {
    std::array<std::thread, ThreadCount> threads;
....
};
}}
```

`ThreadPool<n> pool;` line is throwing an error and only accepting a const value. Is there any way I can pass the **n** value to the **ThreadCount**?

**EDIT**: I want the size of the threads to be changeable after compile time.

Comment: Why not just use a constructor argument?

Comment: @Jim It would be nice if you could provide a small example in the context of above sample.

Comment: @JimV `std::array` requires compile time constant sizing.

Comment: @Scissor Do you intend for the size of `threads` to be changeable after compile-time?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Then you want [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in place of `std::array` to use and @JimV's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template arguments and `std::array`'s size must be known at compile time so that the compiler can generate the correct code.

Options:

Static sizing of everything. Everything is set at compile time and can not be changed at runtime. [Documentation on `constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

```
#include <array>
#include <thread>

template <unsigned ThreadCount>
class ThreadPool {
    std::array<std::thread, ThreadCount> threads;
};

int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned n = 10; // n is fixed at compile time and unchangable.
    ThreadPool<n> pool;  //Error
}
```

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), a parameter on the `threadpool` constructor, and the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class ThreadPool {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
public:
    ThreadPool(unsigned n): threads(n) // constructs threads with n elements
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    unsigned n = 10;
    ThreadPool pool(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved by this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass `n` to it in your case.  In C++, templates are statically compiled. So its parameter has to be a compile time constant. So `constexpr unsigned n = 10;` will make the compiler happy but I don't that what you want.

But if you use C99, which has a feature called variable length array (in C11 it becomes optional) that allows you to declare an array with run time size.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are available by compiler extensions in some C++ compilers, but not recommended. Limited portability as not all compilers support VLA and those that do support them differently. Also ruins the compile-time `const`-ness of `sizeof`